# DP algorithm for covering the distance between two points with a set of intervals

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

**Question:**

Given $n$ points on the $x$-axis, We are asked to provide a **dynamic programming algorithm** to cover the distance between the first and the last point with $k$ closed intervals such that the conditions written below hold:

> (i) The endpoints of these $k$ intervals are chosen from the given $n$ points.  (For example, If $2,3,4,5$ are given, We should provide a way to cover the interval $[2,5]$. But we cannot choose the interval $[2,2.5]$ because $2.5$ is not in the given set.)
>
> (ii) Our algorithm should guarantee that the length of the biggest interval is the minimum possible value.
>
> (iii) The time complexity of our algorithm should be of $O(nk)$.

Note:  It is valid to use intervals with length $0$.

**My try:**

Obviously, The first point between the given $n$ points should be one of the endpoints of one of my covering intervals. So, I should decide for the other endpoint of this interval. What I mean is I have to choose one of the remaining $n-1$ points to be the other endpoint. So, It seems like each time that I'm picking an interval, I should decide for only one of its endpoints.

But, The problem is that this method results in an algorithm of $O(n^2\times k)$ which is not enough because the question asks for $O(nk)$.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance